# Clicking outside card bounds when using an image in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI application where I have a card that contains an image and other elements. I've created a reusable image component called ImageComponent that loads an image from a URL and I've given it a specific size using the frame modifier.

Then, I use this ImageComponent within a card component called ImageCard. However, when clicking on the card, the click gesture seems to extend beyond the bounds of the card, and I suspect that this is due to the image inside the ImageComponent.

I've tried to solve the issue by using the .clipped() modifier on the ImageComponent to ensure that the image doesn't exceed the frame boundaries, and I've also set an explicit size for both the ImageComponent and the card itself. However, the problem persists, and the click area still extends outside the bounds of the card.

Here's the complete code for the ImageComponent and ImageCard components:

```
struct ImageComponent: View {
    var width: CGFloat = 80
    var height: CGFloat = 150
    let imageURL: String
    var body: some View {
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageURL)){ image in
            image.resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .overlay{
                        Color.black.opacity(0.35)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
                    .clipped()
                
        } placeholder: {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "photo")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.8))
             .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height)
        }
    }
}

struct ImageCard: View {
    @State private var imageData: Data? = nil
    var title: String = ""
    var subtitle: String = ""
    let imageURL: String
    var withOverlay: Bool = true
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var onTapGesture: () -> Void = { }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ImageComponent(width: 113, height: 190 ,imageURL: imageURL)
                    .frame(width: 113, height: 190)
                    .clipped()
                if isSelected {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").resizable()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
                if withOverlay {
                    VStack {
                        Text(title)
                            .frame(width: 103, alignment: .leading)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                            .padding(.trailing, 5)
                            .padding(.top, 10)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(subtitle)
                            .frame(width: 103, alignment: .leading)
                            .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                            .padding(.trailing, 5)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.frame(width: 113, height: 190).cornerRadius(15)
            .onTapGesture {
                onTapGesture()
            }
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me solve this issue and ensure that the click gesture is limited only to the card area and doesn't extend beyond its bounds due to the image.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Please feel free to adjust the title, description, and any other details as needed before posting on Stack Overflow. I hope this guide is helpful, and I wish you success in resolving your issue.

Comment: Maybe try the workarounds described in ["Invisible" touchable area outside of real image view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76484711/20386264) ?