# Image fill is overlapping menu SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a menu under an image which has .fill attribute. The menu and image are inside a vstack.

The thing is its not expanding the menu even though its receiving tap gestures. I tried to add .clipped(), .contentShape(), .scaleToFit()... none of them work. Any other view like button etc. are working fine, but menu is kinda broken.

```
  VStack {
                Image(uiImage: MainImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: 280)
                    .gesture(
                        TapGesture(count: 2)
                            .onEnded { // tapped twice
                                if !self.likeManager.IsLiked {
                                    self.likeManager.Likes += 1
                                    self.likeManager.IsLiked = true
                                    discoverProtocol.ImageTap(discoverCell: self, isDoubleTap: true)
                                }
                            }
                            .exclusively(before:
                                TapGesture()
                                .onEnded { // tapped once
                                    discoverProtocol.ImageTap(discoverCell: self, isDoubleTap: false)
                                }
                           )
                    )
                    .overlay(
                        VStack {
                            Spacer()
                            //--------------------------------------------------
                            // TOPIC
                            Text(Topic)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 15, bottom: 5, trailing: 15))
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .background(Color("80000000"))
                        }
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .clipped()
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())

Menu {
     Button {
                            
        } label: {
             Text("LOL")
        }

        } label: {
             Text("MENU")
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `expanding the menu`?

Comment: Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. I tap on the `MENU` and it pops up a menu with the `LOL` button

Comment: I know how to replicate it. Im adding the code above into scroll view using foreach loop. It appears they overlap each other.

Comment: I don't get exactly what your problem is. The menu is workin fine in. my testings. I would add the width to that image though, like this: .frame(width: 280, height: 280).

Comment: The image is overlaping another image if you add the code above in vstack multiple times, which is causing the menu not to work.

Comment: show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you show works as is. If the problem is due to some other code, show that other code.

Comment: Could it be related to this problem? ["Invisible" touchable area outside of real image view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76484711/20386264)

Comment: FWIW, I'm able to repro the issue. using iOS 17.2